# php search script picking up only first condition

Tags: php

Ok, this is my HTML form for search:

```
<form name="search" action="" method="get">
  Search for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
   <select name="field">
    <option value="author">Author</option>
    <option value="papername">Paper name</option>
    <option value="coauthors">Co-authors</option>
    <option value="abstract">Abstract</option>
    <option value="keywords">Keywords</option>
  </select>
 <input type=submit name=search value="search" />
</form>
```

And this is my PHP script for fetching results (first couple of conditions, rest are irrelevant, mostly c/p with variable changes):

```
if($_GET['search'] == "search"){
$loop = "";
$search = !empty($_GET['find']) && ($_GET['find'] != "")?trim($_GET['find']):false;
$field = !empty($_GET['field'])?trim($_GET['field']):false;
  if ($search == ""){
  echo "Please enter search conditions !";
  }
    elseif ($search) {
    echo "<u>Searched term</u>:"." ".$search."<br />"."<u>In</u>:"." ".$field."<br/>";

    if(($field == "Author") || ($search != "")) {                   
    $author_query = mysql_query("SELECT p_authors FROM papers WHERE p_authors LIKE '%$search%'");
    $author_output = mysql_num_rows($author_query);
        if($author_output > 0){
            while ($loop = mysql_fetch_assoc($author_query)) {
                                print_r($loop);
                }
            }
    else {
    echo "No match !";
      }                 
    }
    elseif(($field == "papername") || ($search != "")){
    $author_query = mysql_query("SELECT p_name FROM papers WHERE p_name LIKE '%$search%'");
    $author_output = mysql_num_rows($author_query);
        if($author_output > 0){
        while ($loop = mysql_fetch_assoc($author_query)) {
            print_r($loop);
            }
    }
        else {
          echo "No match !";
        }   
            }
     etc ...
```

Thing is, i only get output results when option value (Author) is selected (with some keywords in search field), but when i change option value (like papername and others), i get echoed error. Looks like only first if condition (with $field == "Author") is passing through, i cant figure out what is wrong here ? Thx

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated, consider changing it to `mysqli` or `PDO` objects.

Comment: what error you get????

Comment: There is no error, i only got echo "No match" for anything else except when `$field` Author is selected

Comment: Also, you'll have a lot of `elseif`s that way. I suggest you review your logic and apply `switch case` use instead.

Answer (score 0):

*Strictly answering your question with the information you provided:* If you're falling under `else` clause, it obviously means your `if` clause wasn't fulfilled. In your case, `$author_output <= 0`, which lead us to believe **1)** your query is returning no results and therefore you must review your table contents, SELECT parameters and etc or **2)** your query is returning error and you're not dealing with it as you should.

And as stated in comments, avoid using `mysql_` deprecated functions and consider using `mysqli_` ones or build `PDO` objects.

Answer (score 0):

in your if statement you are using OR(||($search != ""))condition which gets always true as its not null so its executing everytime and other elseif blocks never executes try replacing that with AND(&&) condition as follows

```
if(($field == "Author") && ($search != "")) {                   
$author_query = mysql_query("SELECT p_authors FROM papers WHERE p_authors LIKE '%$search%'");
$author_output = mysql_num_rows($author_query);
    if($author_output > 0){
        while ($loop = mysql_fetch_assoc($author_query)) {
                            print_r($loop);
            }
        }
else {
echo "No match !";
  }                 
}
```

Comment: i also see you already checking for ($search == "") not empty in the code above so you don't even need the AND condition to check its empty...